# Publish artifacts to S3 does not copy the war file

Tags: amazon-s3, jenkins

I am trying to publish my build artifacts to S3 via jenkins and for that I have done the below

1. Installed S3 plugin
2. Created an Amazon S3 Profile by adding the public key and secret key via Manage Jenkins > Configure System.
3. Selected the "Publish artifacts to S3" post build action

I know I have provided the source and destination correctly as the build says file not found when incorrect and creates a destination folder in the S3 bucket initially.

But It does not copy the war file to the required folder in the S3 bucket and there is no error in the console too.

The console output is as below.

```
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/<project_name>/workspace/trunk/pom.xml to <path>/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/<project_name>-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/<project_name>/workspace/trunk/target/<project_name>.war to <path>/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/<project_name>-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war
channel stopped
Publish artifacts to S3 Bucket Using S3 profile: Dev_S3_profile
Publish artifacts to S3 Bucket bucket=fr-jenkins-deployments/1_dev, file=<project_name>.war region = <region>
```

Can somebody help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the **Manage artifacts** option during the publish artifacts post-build step.

I've had the same problem, and it was quite annoying.